# Change factor label ggplot when scale_x_reordered() is present

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am creating a box plot in which I have used scale_x_reordered() after adjusting the order of factors on the x axis.

I am now trying to change the label of one factor. I had previously been doing this using:

scale_x_discrete(labels=c("old_label" = "new_label"))

However, I cannot use both scale_x_discrete() and scale_x_reordered() in the same plot. Does anyone know of a fix so that I can change a label and keep scale_x_reordered?

My ggplot is based off of this very helpful example: [linked here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/)

The change I am trying to make is equivalent to manually changing the name "Michael" to "Mike".

Comment: Try giving `labels=c("old_label" = "new_label")` as an argument to `scale_x_reordered`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I get the error message: "Error in discrete_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend"), "position_d",  : 
  formal argument "labels" matched by multiple actual arguments"

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result I would suggest to recode your factor before applying `reorder_within`.

The reason is that `reorder_within` transforms the factor levels to make the reordering within facets work. Inside `scale_x_reordered` a re-transformation is applied via the `labels` argument to show the original levels or labels. That's why you can't make use of the `labels` argument.

In the following example taken from the link you posted I make use of `dplyr::recode(name, "Michael" = "Mike")` just before `reorder_within`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(babynames)
library(tidytext)

top_names <- babynames %>%
  filter(year >= 1950,
         year < 1990) %>%
  mutate(decade = (year %/% 10) * 10) %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  count(name, wt = n, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup

top_names %>%
  group_by(decade) %>%
  top_n(15) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(decade = as.factor(decade),
         name = recode(name, "Michael" = "Mike"),
         name = reorder_within(name, n, decade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, n, fill = decade)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~decade, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(y = "Number of babies per decade",
       x = NULL,
       title = "What were the most common baby names in each decade?",
       subtitle = "Via US Social Security Administration")
#> Selecting by n
```

[image]